# Uploading video to Azure Storage through Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, video, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to upload a video file to my Azure Storage account. I've got it working with images, however trying to view an uploaded video gives the message "Video format or MIME-type is not supported". The video format is mp4.

I use the following code to upload:

```
public async Task UploadVideo(Stream video, string path)
{

    var container = GetContainer("videos");

    // Creates the container if it does not exist
    await CreateContainer(container);

    //Gets the file extension
    string lastPart = path.Split('.').Last();

    // Uploads the video to the blob storage
    CloudBlockBlob videoBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
    videoBlob.Properties.ContentType = "video/" + lastPart;
    await videoBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(video);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Edit:

Here's the code I use to capture video on the phone:

```
    private async Task TakeVideoButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
        {
            Name = "video.mp4",
            Directory = "DefaultVideos",
        });

        if (mediaFile == null)
            return;

        await DisplayAlert("Video Recorded", "Location: " + mediaFile.Path, "OK");
        videoStream = mediaFile.GetStream();

        file.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What gives you that error message?

Comment: If I try to access the video https://wellfitter.blob.core.windows.net/kl-kl-2/testvideo_591c92b8-3df9-4362-bab4-c1dca3390312.mp4

Comment: Is it possible that the file is just corrupted? It appears Azure tries to deliver the file as an MP4 video, so that part is ok. Did you try just downloading the file again and playing it locally?

Comment: I quickly downloaded the file (146 KB only?) and couldn't play it locally, so I would assume the file was uploaded incomplete. Your code looks ok - can you check the file size, and that your `video` stream is working as expected?

Comment: As  Philipp Sumi  mentioned that  you could check whether original video file could work. If it works locally. Then you could upload the video directly with [Azure storage explore](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to check whether it could work. I test with you code, it works correctly on my side. I check the video file from browser.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The video I upload is recorded on emulator, so that might be the issue? I'm using a plugin called Xam.Plugin.Media to capture video and images. See the edit in my original post for that code. I think I might try to run it on my phone instead, to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this on my phone instead of my emulator and it worked perfectly there, so I'm going to assume it's purely a emulator related issue.